# R language, SETAR model, non linear models

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

I'm using `tsDyn` package in R we can build SETAR model, but then I want to use the same obtained model with another data, for example :

```
SETAR 2 model ( 2 regimes)
Coefficients:
Low regime:
const.L      phiL.1      phiL.2 
-0.04704707  1.36142715 -0.72764118
High regime:
const.H     phiH.1     phiH.2 
0.1162651  1.5441993 -0.5903389 
Threshold:
Variable: Z(t) = + (0) X(t)+ (1)X(t-1)
Value: 0.9071
```

I create this model using 100 samples, but then I need to use it with 1000 samples to test its performance with other models. Thank you.